# Javascript Quiz not progressing to next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to make a quiz whereby question is only displayed one question at a time and in total, users only need to answer 3 questions correctly before they are allowed to progress. At any time, if the user were to answer any question wrongly, the user will be directed to the GameOver page.

I have currently managed to set the randomised Questions to appear and when user chooses the wrong answer, they will be directed to the GameOver page.

At this point, I am stuck at the part where it is always showing Question1, even though user has selected the correct answer.

Could I get some help on how to call the next question  when user has selected the correct answer from the current question?

Thanks

```js
var questionOrder = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"];

var answerOrder = [
  ["Yes", "No"],
  ["Yes", "No"],
  ["Yes", "No"]
];
var CorrectAnswers = ["1", "2", "2"];

//To Set random Question
var random_QuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionOrder.length);

//Assign Variable to generate random question for the quiz
var question = questionOrder[random_QuestionIndex];
var answerList = answerOrder[random_QuestionIndex];

function showQuestion() {
  //Randomise Question
  //Code to generate random question for the quiz
  AnswerIndex = "";

  $('#Question_List').html(question);
  //Generate random answers in relation to the questions
  $('#STBAnswer_01').hide();
  $('#STBAnswer_02').hide();
  $('#STBAnswer_03').hide();
  //$('#STBAnswer_04').hide();

  for (i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++) {
    $('#STBAnswer_0' + (i + 1)).attr('src', answerList[i]);
    $('#STBAnswer_0' + (i + 1)).show();
  }
}

function selectSTBAnswer(index) {
  AnswerIndex = index + "";
  console.log(AnswerIndex);
  console.log(CorrectAnswers[random_QuestionIndex]);
  //Conditional Answer Check; if answer is wrong, GameOver, else proceed to next Question
  if (CorrectAnswers[random_QuestionIndex] != AnswerIndex) {
    console.log("IncorrectAnswer");
    $('#QnA').fadeOut({
      duration: slideDuration,
      queue: false
    });
    $('#GameOver').fadeIn({
      duration: slideDuration,
      queue: false
    });
  } else {


    console.log("CorrectAnswer");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      $('#Question_List').fadeOut();
      $('#STBAnswer_01').fadeOut();
      $('#STBAnswer_02').fadeOut();
      $('#STBAnswer_03').fadeOut();
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="QnA" align="center" style="position:absolute; height:1920px; width:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=1; top:0px; left:0px; ">

  <div id="Question_List" style="position:absolute; z-index=99; width:900px; height:200px; top:50px; left:100px; font-size:45px; font-family:'HelveticaNeue'; color:#fff;"></div>

  <img id="STBAnswer_01" style="z-index=99; position:absolute; top:250px; left:50px; border:0px;" onclick="selectSTBAnswer('1');">
  <img id="STBAnswer_02" style="z-index=99; position:absolute; top:350px; left:50px; border:0px;" onclick="selectSTBAnswer('2');">
  <img id="STBAnswer_03" style="z-index=99; position:absolute; top:450px; left:50px; border:0px;" onclick="selectSTBAnswer('3');">
</div>

<div id="GameOver" align="center" style="position:absolute; height:1920px; width:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=4; top:0px; left:0px; ">
  GAME OVER
</div>
```

I am stuck at when user selects the correct answer and it doesn't transition to the next question but stuck at the currect 1st question.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this slightly modified HTML (I added classes `class="answers"`, alt to make images valid and modified style to make it easier to do and see)  I resisted removing all that style from markup and putting it in CSS where it should be.

Still a bit messy but you can clean that up before a production release.

Run it a few times here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/3vr1t002/

```
<div id="QnA" align="center">
  <div id="Question_List" style="position:absolute; z-index=99; width:400px; height:100px; top:50px; left:100px; font-size:45px; font-family:'HelveticaNeue'; color:green;"></div>

  <img id="STBAnswer_01" alt="first" class="answers" style="z-index=99; position:absolute; top:100px; left:50px; border:0px;">
  <img id="STBAnswer_02" alt="secon" class="answers" style="z-index=99; position:absolute; top:200px; left:50px; border:0px;">
  <img id="STBAnswer_03" alt="third" class="answers" style="z-index=99; position:absolute; top:300px; left:50px; border:0px;">
</div>

<div id="GameOver" align="center" style="position:absolute; height:1920px; width:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=4; top:0px; left:0px; ">
  GAME OVER
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
console.clear();
var myquiz = myquiz || {
  questionOrder: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"],
  answerOrder: [
    ["Yes", "No"],
    ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"],
    ["Yes", "No"]
  ],
  CorrectAnswers: ["1", "2", "2"],
  numberCorrect: 0
};

var question, answerList, random_QuestionIndex;
//Temp Answer Variable
var AnswerIndex = "";
var slideDuration = 100;

function getRandom() {
  //To Set random Question
  random_QuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myquiz.questionOrder.length);
  console.log("rqi" + random_QuestionIndex);
  //Assign Variable to generate random question for the quiz
  question = myquiz.questionOrder[random_QuestionIndex];
  answerList = myquiz.answerOrder[random_QuestionIndex];
  $('#Question_List').html(question);
  //Generate random answers in relation to the questions
  $('.answers').hide();
  for (var i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++) {
    $('.answers').eq(i).attr('src', answerList[i]).show();
  }
}


function selectSTBAnswer(index) {
  AnswerIndex = index + "";
  console.log(AnswerIndex);
  console.log(myquiz.CorrectAnswers[random_QuestionIndex]);
  //Conditional Answer Check; if answer is wrong, GameOver, else proceed to next Question
  if (myquiz.CorrectAnswers[random_QuestionIndex] != AnswerIndex) {
    console.log("IncorrectAnswer");
    $('#QnA').fadeOut({
      duration: slideDuration,
      queue: false
    });
    $('#GameOver').fadeIn({
      duration: slideDuration,
      queue: false
    });
  } else {

    console.log("CorrectAnswer");
    myquiz.numberCorrect++;
    getRandom();
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {}
  }
}
$('.answers').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  selectSTBAnswer(index);
  if (myquiz.numberCorrect === 3) {
    alert("winner winner chicken dinner");
    myquiz.numberCorrect = 0;
  }
});
getRandom();
```

Comment: so the for loop that I have is absolutely redundant

Comment: what is the meaning of `var myquiz = myquiz || {...};`. Why do you need to do that??What is the difference between the one that you have set and the global variable that I have set?

Comment: That segment does not replace the old one if one previously exists.  Not a huge deal in this instance.

Comment: As to your question regarding the global, this is more robust.  If someone puts ANTHER global in there with the same name yours would be overwritten (in parts) so this puts it in a namespace (you decide that) and then accesses all those parts in there.  Bottom line is to try to not pollute the global namespace

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you select a question at the begining in a variable that is scoped to your script.

```
//Assign Variable to generate random question for the quiz
var question = questionOrder[random_QuestionIndex];
```

But when a answer is selected, you call:

```
$('#Question_List').html(question);
```

Without affecting a new value to question, so the "new" html you put in the node is the same and the question does not change visually.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but in a way, I will still need to append the new question to `$('#Question_List')`. So that means, I will have erase the cache first??

Comment: @Luke You have two options I think, Both of them require you to take an array of questions, and randomize it.     1) Use `html()` once to add all of the questions in your HTML DOM. Then you can use `hide()` and `show()` to display the question you want. You would need to keep an index in the html to be able to select the questions you want to hide and show using JQuery.           2) You use `html()` for each question in order to replace the previous question by the next. I find it easier because you just have to keep track of indexes and arrays in javascript.

Comment: @Luke And yes the second option will delete the html for the previous question :/ But you can keep your history in a variable and call `html()` again whenever you want to show an 'old' question

Comment: I am still clueless, I have made the questions and all the answers to fadeOut. If I were to use the same line `$('#Question_List').html(question);`, it will still be the same as before. I am not seeing the light in this

Comment: I have earlier tried to set the random method within the for loop but it is still not able to show the next question. Please help, what should I do next. am seriously not seeing the light to tis puzzle